# Reverse Guessing Game for java

Tags: java, random

I've been trying to create a reverse guessing game wherein the user will input a number and then the program/bot will try to guess what number the user gave. I have a problem with random generator in the program. For example, when the user inputs a number such as 157, the bot will generate a number. If the number that bot gave is lower than 157, the user will then click the higher button (lower button if the number is higher). My problem is it doesn't generate properly and just give a random number.

I've tried changing the formula for `Math.random()` but I still can't figure it out.

Here's my code for the jbutton (higher) in netbeans :

```
if(con > con2) {
    int generator = (int)(Math.random() * (1 + high - low))+low;
    String conv = Integer.toString(generator);
    jTextField2.setText(conv);
}
```

Comment: We're going to need more information than this to solve the problem. Please provide a [reprex] :)

Comment: Can you expand on "it doesn't generate properly and just give a random number"? You're generating random numbers, so I would expect a random number as the output

Answer (score 0):

Your problem very likely does not lie in your random number generation. When I run the following:

```
int high = 20;
int low = 10;
for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    int generator = (int)(Math.random() * (1 + high - low))+low;
    System.out.print(generator+" ");
}
```

I get the following output:

> 18 19 12 11 19 17 15 19 14 16 16 14 10 20 13 20 11 14 20 15

This generates random numbers between 10 and 20, inclusive. So, if you're running into a problem with your random number generation, there are a few possibilities:

Your `jTextField2.setText` value is getting ignored

Your `jTextField2.setText` value is getting overridden

Your values `low` and `high` are not what you think they are

Your values `low` and `high` are being changed at the same time/before your `if` statement runs

The condition `(con > con2)` for your `if` statement is never satisfied, so the `if` is never invoked in the first place

The best way to resolve this problem is for you to debug the remaining parts of your program, because the random number generation is clearly functional.